# Recursively loop through the DOM tree and remove unwanted tags?

Tags: php, html, dom

```
$tags = array(
    "applet" => 1,  
    "script" => 1
);

$html = file_get_contents("test.html");
$dom = new DOMdocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$body = $xpath->query("//body")->item(0);
```

I'm about looping through the "body" of the web page and remove all unwanted tags listed in the $tags array but I can't find a way. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$tags = array(
    "applet" => 1,  
    "script" => 1
);

$html = file_get_contents("test.html");
$dom = new DOMdocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

for($i=0; $i<count($tags); ++$i) {
   $list = $xpath->query("//".$tags[$i]);
   for($j=0; $j<$list->length; ++$j) {
      $node = $list->item($j);
      if ($node == null) continue;
      $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
   }
}

$string = $dom->saveXML();
```

Something like that.

Comment: You should only increment `$j` if no removal was performed. Otherwise you skip elements.

Answer (score 6):

Had you considered [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)? starting with your own html sanitizing is just re-inventing the wheel, and isn't easy to accomplish.

Furthermore, a blacklist approach is also bad, see [SO/why-use-a-whitelist-for-html-sanitizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475784/why-use-a-whitelist-for-html-sanitizing)

You may also be interested in reading [how to cinfigure allowed tags & attributes](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,2928,2929#msg-2929) or [testing HTML Purifier demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php)

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip. I will use a whitelist instead. And oh, happy new year to you all :)