# Strip tag with class in PHP

Tags: php

So I need to strip the `span` tags of class `tip`.
So that would be `<span class="tip">` and the corresponding `</span>`, and everything inside it...

I suspect a regular expression is needed but I terribly suck at this.

---

Laugh...

```
<?php
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Gives no error... But

```
<?php
$str = preg_replace('<span class="tip">.+</span>', "", '<span class="rss-title"></span><span class="rss-link">linkylink</span><span class="rss-id"></span><span class="rss-content"></span><span class=\"rss-newpost\"></span>');
echo $str;
?>
```

Gives me the error:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '.' in <A FILE> on line 4
```

previously, the error was at the `);` in the 2nd line, but now.... >.>

Comment: Mmmm, the *proper* way would be doing it with a DOM parser - it would also work for your "and everything inside it" requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursively loop through the DOM tree and remove unwanted tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562769/recursively-loop-through-the-dom-tree-and-remove-unwanted-tags) I took the liberty of marking this as a duplicate even if it isn't one 100%. You'd have to test for the desired tag and class name before deleting.

Comment: That is not good. That method doesn't allow me to check for the class. And I can't remove all the `span`s.

Comment: What are you talking about? Of course that method allows you to check for the class. `if $node->class == "tip" ...` and I don't see why it shouldn't remove all `span`s`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple regular expression like:

```
<span class="tip">.+</span>
```

Wont work, the issue being that if another span was opened and closed inside the tip span, your regex will terminate with its ending, rather than the tip one. DOM Based tools like the one linked in the comments will really provide a more reliable answer.

As per my comment below, you need to add pattern delimiters when working with regular expressions in PHP.

```
<?php
$str = preg_replace('\<span class="tip">.+</span>\', "", '<span class="rss-title"></span><span class="rss-link">linkylink</span><span class="rss-id"></span><span class="rss-content"></span><span class=\"rss-newpost\"></span>');
echo $str;
?>
```

may be moderately more successful. Please take a look at the documentation page for the function in question.

Comment: Ok so how do I apply this regex to my string? xD

Comment: You would likely use preg_replace() to replace the matched string with nothing (an empty string). Don't forget that you need regular expression delimiters, the examples on http://us3.php.net/preg_replace use the forward slash as a delimiter.

Comment: I have a problem with that function. It doesn't work. It complains about an error when closing the arguments (`);`)...

Comment: Please look at the third comment in this thread, or my updated answer.

Comment: This breaks if the tag contains _any_ other attributes. You also forgot your regex delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "proper" method (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526457/php-convert-string-to-htmlentities/5526701#5526701)).

Input:

```
<?php
$str = '<div>lol wut <span class="tip">remove!</span><span>don\'t remove!</span></div>';
?>
```

Code:

```
<?php
function recurse(&$doc, &$parent) {
   if (!$parent->hasChildNodes())
      return;

   for ($i = 0; $i < $parent->childNodes->length; ) {
      $elm = $parent->childNodes->item($i);
      if ($elm->nodeName == "span") {
         $class = $elm->attributes->getNamedItem("class")->nodeValue;
         if (!is_null($class) && $class == "tip") {
            $parent->removeChild($elm);
            continue;
         }
      }

      recurse($doc, $elm);
      $i++;
   }
}

// Load in the DOM (remembering that XML requires one root node)
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML("<document>" . $str . "</document>");

// Iterate the DOM
recurse($doc, $doc->documentElement);

// Output the result
foreach ($doc->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
   echo $doc->saveXML($node);
}
?>
```

Output:

```
<div>lol wut <span>don't remove!</span></div>
```

Comment: A valid HTML contents (full or snippet) may not be XML valid, so your parsing may fail.

Comment: If you have an actual, full HTML document, you can load it with `loadHTML`. Else, tough noogie.

Answer (score 0):

Now without regexp, and without heavy XML parsing:

```
$html = ' ... <span class="tip"> hello <span id="x"> man </span> </span> ... ';
$tag = '<span class="tip">';
$tag_close = '</span>';
$tag_familly = '<span';

$tag_len = strlen($tag);

$p1 = -1;
$p2 = 0;
while ( ($p2!==false)  && (($p1=strpos($html, $tag, $p1+1))!==false) ) {
  // the tag is found, now we will search for its corresponding closing tag
  $level = 1;
  $p2 = $p1;
  $continue = true; 
  while ($continue) {
     $p2 = strpos($html, $tag_close, $p2+1);
     if ($p2===false) {
       // error in the html contents, the analysis cannot continue
       echo "ERROR in html contents";
       $continue = false;
       $p2 = false; // will stop the loop
     } else {
       $level = $level -1;
       $x = substr($html, $p1+$tag_len, $p2-$p1-$tag_len);
       $n = substr_count($x, $tag_familly);
       if ($level+$n<=0) $continue = false;
     }
  }
  if ($p2!==false) {
    // delete the couple of tags, the farest first
    $html = substr_replace($html, '', $p2, strlen($tag_close));
    $html = substr_replace($html, '', $p1, $tag_len);
  }
}
```