# How can I remove all <span> tags and their respective content, including other nested elements?

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

I've tried a few solutions which only remove the the tags themselves leaving the content and any other nested

Regular Expression,

```
preg_replace('/<span\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/ig', '', $page->body);
```

Tried using HTML purifier also,

```
$purifier->set('Core.HiddenElements', array('span'));

$purifier->set('HTML.ForbiddenElements', array('span'));
```

Comment: show us what you tried. maybe you missed something

Comment: @svarog Updated, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your actual strings and the things you tried you could use a regular expression (assuming your span tags are only span tags).
A more "appropriate" solution however would be to use an html parser like [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

You can use the function `document.getElementsByName("span");` to get all the span elements and remove them from the document object.
Then use [saveHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) to get the html code back.

You will get something like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($yourpage);

$root = $doc->documentElement;

// we retrieve the spans and remove it from the book
$spans = $book->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach ($spans as $span){
    $root->removeChild($span);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thank you for not endorsing RegEx as a tool to match arbitrary HTML.

Comment: Non working example. and probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562769/